# Intro of loading screen

Tags: android, multithreading, android-intent

At the app I'm developing, I'm interested in an intro of a loading screen. Which automatically move to the next screen after a duration.

The intro itself, is working just fine. As well as the thread who delaying the system.
My problem is to make them work together.

The code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

ImageView iv;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.loading_screen);


    final Thread t1=new Thread(new Runnable() {


    public void run() {

        iv=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgBtn1);
        iv.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.loading_i_animation);
        AnimationDrawable anim=(AnimationDrawable) iv.getBackground();
        anim.start();

        }
    });

    t1.start();


    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        finish();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    finally {
        Intent st=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Welcome.class);
        startActivity(st);
    }


    }
```

The result of this code is opening a white screen for the thread sleep-time duration. and after that open the "Welcome.class" screen via the intent.

It's just skipping the loading_screen, as is wasn't even exist.

I hope you guys could please help my with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You put your `sleep` on the UI thread which prevents Android to show anything until it finishes. Try the following code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.loading_screen);

    iv=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgBtn1);
    iv.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.loading_i_animation);
    AnimationDrawable anim=(AnimationDrawable) iv.getBackground();
    anim.start();

    new Handler().postDelayed(
        new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Intent st=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Welcome.class);
                startActivity(st);
                finish();
            }
        }, 2000);
}
```

This way the delay will run on a separated thread, but after 2 seconds it changes back to the main thread and runs the code you specified in your `Runnable`

Comment: I understands the idea. However the code isn't compiler in my system. Could you please rewrite it?

Comment: I am sorry, I actually did it on purpose. My goal is to show the loading_screen and after 2 seconds move to the other screen.

So the thread that stopped the system indeed was at the right place.

Comment: The problem is, that you are blocking the system from every action (showing your screen for example). In my code you do not block it, so it shows the UI, but after the 2 second delay it changes to the other activity.

Comment: Ok. But still when I put your code, I have compiler problems.
Such as:
> Handler cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: You're right, I found the problem (missing parenthesis after Runnable), fixed it in my answer.

Comment: Good, now the compiler problem is gone. 
But the result haven't changed... There is a white screen instead of the loading one.

Comment: Updated my answer, you should remove the animation start from `t1`.